# Whitehead Theorem with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

By the Whitehead Theorem, if a map $f:X\to Y$ between connected CW-complexes induces isomorphisms $\pi_1 (f) :\pi_1 (X)\to \pi_1 (Y)$ and $H_n (\tilde{f}):H_n (\tilde{X},\mathbb{Z})\to H_n (\tilde{Y},\mathbb{Z})$ for $n\geq 2$, then $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

My question: Does the Whitehead Theorem still hold if  $f:X\to Y$ induces isomorphisms $\pi_1 (f) :\pi_1 (X)\to \pi_1 (Y)$ and $H_n (\tilde{f}):H_n (\tilde{X},\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (G))\to H_n (\tilde{Y},\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (G))$ for $n\geq 2$?

Comment: So $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1(G)$ is a free abelian group, and thus by the Universal Coefficient Theorem $H_n(\tilde{X},\mathbb{Z}\pi_1(G))\simeq H_n(\tilde{X})\otimes\mathbb{Z}\pi_1(G)$ which is further isomorphic to $H_n(\tilde{X})^{r}$, where $r$ is the rank of $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1(G)$. I think all of those transformations are natural. So: if $(\tilde{f}^*)^{r}$ is an isomorphism then is $\tilde{f}^*$ an isomorphism? If yes, then we go back to Whitehead. Which I think is trivially true, but I'm not exactly sure if all those transformations are natural. The devil is in the details.